# Glassfish with Oracle DS

Tags: oracle, glassfish

I am using glassfish 3.1 and configure Oracle Datasource. However, I tried to Ping from glassfish admin console, but hitting an error with oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource not found. What could be the Issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html - you need to insert Oracle jdbc driver manually as it does not come bundled with Glassfish 3.1 installation. Just put the required jar into domain/lib directory.

Driver jar is downloadable from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html